# How to make flex div scrollable

Tags: scroll, element

Let's say I have 3 DIVs like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        .....
    </div>
    <div id="c">
        .....
        a lot of elements
        .....
    </div>
</div>
```

styles are defined

```
#a { 
   position: absolute; 
   right: 100px; 
   width: 100px; 
   top: 0; 
   bottom: 0; 
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

#b {

}

#c {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I don't know height of DIV B, but I want DIV C to scroll it's content in case it doesn't fit into DIV a. Probably this picture helps:

[image]

When I define it as above, DIV C is "veeeery" high ( goes beyond bottom of DIV a ) and it doesn't scroll its content. Is there a CSS way, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to find the solution - DIV C needs style

```
flex: 1 100%;
```